# How to set image to be tabbable

Tags: html

I have an image and I want the user to be able to naviagte to it using the tab button. I am unable to set the tab-index due to the way the page is changed dynamically. How can I set the image to be tabbable?

Comment: Please be more specific... you're unable because page is dynamically changed or because you can't set tabindex to the image? To set tabindex to images, try wrapping them inside anchors `<a href="#" tabindex="1"><img ... /></a>`
Oh and, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be appreciated.

Comment: I am as specific as I can be. The page is changed dynamically. ie. with javascript. And I want the image to be able to be tabbed to, I also dont care what position it is. I didnt see the need to set up a jsfiddle for a simple question. I'll try that anchor thing now.

Comment: If it changes dynamically with js, create the anchors with `tabindex` attribute set `$("<a>").attr("tabindex",1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wrapping them inside anchors `<a tabindex="1"><img src="..." /></a>` and set `tabindex` attribute to dynamically created elements `$("<a>").attr("tabindex",tabindex)`:

```
var anchor = $("<a>").attr("href",image_link).attr("tabindex", tabindex);
var img = $("<img>").attr("src", image_src).appendTo(anchor);
```

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/EsEeN/

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the image in a span which has a tabindex of 0.

```html
<span tabindex="0">
  <img src="./img.png" alt="img.png">
</span>
```

But I don't see the utility in doing that. If the users use only keyboard or you ant to have good accessibility for your app this wouldn't make much sense.

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex#accessibility_concerns

Comment: Thanks! To add: note that 0 is a special and recommended value, because it lets the page choose its own order besides indicating that it is tabbable at all. Setting to a negative value would indicate that it cannot be selected using tab.